# Resize console while running jar file from .bat file

Tags: java, batch-file, jar, console, executable-jar

I've created a .bat file to launch a .jar file but I need to expand the console size at the same time.
My jar file is a simple java application, and I launch my jar like :

> start ./jdk-1.8-portable/bin/java.exe -jar MyApp-jar-with-dependencies.jar MyConfig.xml

I've tried to put the command  "mode con: cols=160 lines=78" before or after, but the start command launch is own console over it and delete the well dimensioned one... Any idea plz ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: tried removing the start in the beginning?

Comment: If I remove the start it doesn't open a console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `start /B java ...`. This will not create a new console window.